# Magnifying tool on MIDI files?

Tags: midi

I am searching for any interactive tool out there that will help me read and write MIDI files, just by entering binary data.

I mean, when I write binary in the binary pane, it tells me in the other pane when I've entered and vice versa.

I read [this](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm) page, and there were mentioned a few programs: "REC.EXE", "DEC.EXE" and "MIDINOTE.PS", I tried to google them but didn't get much.

Am I clear?
I am looking for a tool that reads the binary values of a MIDI file and tells me (tab or comma delimited etc.) on each bit what it does.

Is anyone aware of any tool that offer a similar features criteria?

**Update**: Read my comment please.

Comment: If you want information to help write you own MIDI reading/writing code, that would make sense here. Looking for an existing tool to do so doesn't seem to (i.e., that's about using a program, not about programming).

Comment: Yes. I need to develop an API that writes MIDI files according to user demands. it doesn't have to play the MIDI, it has to WRITE the file.
So in order to get easier with understand the binary part or even real-life example of existing MIDI files will also be warmly welcommed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MidiPiano](http://code.google.com/p/virtualpiano/) - a free (no open-sourced) application was basically what I was looking for.

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) and [JFugue](http://jfugue.org) helped me a lot too.

[This](http://cnx.org/content/m15049/latest/) and [this](http://www.recordingblogs.com/sa/Wiki/tabid/58/Default.aspx?topic=Musical+Instrument+Digital+Interface+%28MIDI%29) links were also pretty helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [MIDI File Dump utility](http://www.pnelsoncomposer.com/software/MIDIFile/) for Win32/DOS systems, but I can't say that I've tried it yet.  It's also open-source, so you can read through the code to get a better hint of how to correctly read/write MIDI files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything like that that exists. My advice to you would be to download the source code for an open-source MIDI tool, compile it with debugging support, start it in debugging mode, open a MIDI, and then step through the program as it reads the MIDI file information. That way, not only do you see how the binary information is treated directly, but you start to get a sense of MIDI programming in general.